# Is it possible to tell web crawlers to agree to a site's TOS before indexing?

Tags: web-crawlers, robots.txt

Is there a way with `robots.txt` or page headers to inform the managers of web crawlers they must agree to a terms of service prior to indexing any crawled pages?

Comment: Please note this is not intended to be a question about trying to keep malicious bots from being malicious.

Comment: Bots can't read. How do you expect them to understand your terms of service?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller The bots are controlled by humans.

Comment: Search engine bots don't have humans directing their every move.  They automatically crawl based on pre-programmed rules.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller The managers could program a rule that alerts the managers to a site requesting the managers acknowledge reviewing the site's TOS before indexing.

Comment: What do you have in your terms of service that would require that type of individual attention from search engines?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller You are asking a purely subjective question framed to make me look overly-self-important. Stop doing that, it's disrespectful of your users, even though it does earn you brownie points with the site's cheerleaders.

Comment: I'm trying to ask what you're really trying to achieve. Even if there is no way to get crawlers to agree to a terms of service there might be a way to make crawlers behave in the way you want through some other means.

Answer (score 1):

The robots.txt spec does not allow for this - and even if it did, there are legal issues - a robot can not provide informed consent,/it does not have a mind so there can be no meeting of the minds.  (If there is no meeting of the minds there is no contract)

Its likely to be an exercise in futility, but you could set up pages with arbitrary headers requiring a particular action described in the headers to accept terms and conditions - of-course robots would not consent because they can't.

Even if you *could* do do the trick you are attempting, contracts of adhesion (ie take it or leave it, with no ability to negotiate) are more difficult to enforce then negotiated contracts.